# How to order list based on some id found in another list c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I know there are plenty of question about this topic but none of them seems to solve my answer (or at least from what i have found) pardon me if this is a duplicate question.

I have a list that i gather from SQL containing two properties `SequenceId` and `Relevant`:

```cs
var sequenceList = await context.SequenceDB.Where(c => c.PeopleId == peopleId).Select(c => {
  SequenceId = c.SequenceId,
  Relevant = c.Relevant
}).OrderBy(c => c.Relevant).ToListAsync();
```

Then i have another list like so:

```cs
var secondList = await context.Activity.ToListAsync();
```

**FYI**

- the second list has multiple properties (hence column in the database) and one of them is `SequenceId` pointing to that `SequenceId` in `SequenceDB`.

What i want is to order the `secondList` based on the order of GUID's in the `sequenceList`.

**BUT**:

- I just need to order them NOT exclude them from the list. And i don't want to exclude any of the elements from `secondList`
- The result will be a list of `Activity` with as first elements the ones from `sequenceList` and then the rest

If you think this is a duplicate question please point me to the right one and i'll delete this one.

It seems simple even though is not for me.

Comment: Use the IndexOf in the other list in the OrderBy.  So if you have int[] sortOrder = {5, 7, 4} the sequenceList.OrderBy(x => sortOrder.IndexOf(x.id))

Comment: @jdweng That would be pretty slow, wouldn't it?

Comment: It would depend on the size of the order list the amount of time.  You could speed up in a long list by making it a dictionary (or hash).

Comment: Probably guids are not such a good data choice for this problem. You can probably get a better result by creating a view in the database (or equivalent that will accept parameters). It seems like you can also combine the above into a single query and you can `join` on the necessary key. Otherwise you can create a new class / viewmodel and `.Select((element, index) => new ...` ; the new class would then have the index as an int you can sort on...

Answer (score 1):

You can join the lists using an outer join, so something like this should work.

First, number each row in secondList so we can retain the order for items which don't match those in the sequenceList.

```
var indexedSecondList = secondList.Select((e, index) => new { e, index });

(from r in indexedSecondList 
join s in sequenceList on r.e.SequenceId equals s.SequenceId into tmp
from t in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
 
 orderby t != null ? 0 : 1 ,                            // Sort the entries that are in SequenceList first
         t != null ? t.Relevant : (System.Guid?) null , // Then sort by Relevant 
         r.index                                        // Finally sort by original order in secondList

 select r.e).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i'll try this as soon as possible. But i think it might do what i need.